# Show that the following f is integrable on every Jordan bounded set? (proof verifying)

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Q: let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy that for each open ball $U$ then $f$ is integrable (such that $\int|f|<\infty$)) over $U$ and $\int_{U}f=v(U)$ where v is the volume of $U$. Show that for every Jordan bounded set $E$ it is that $f$ is integrable over $E$ and $\int_{E}f=v(E)$

- Jordan bounded sets are sets with negligible boundary.

Hey, I would really like to know if the following proof holds:

Let $E$ be a bounded Jordan set. for each $x\in E$ denote $B_x=B(x,r_x)$ where $r_x$ will be stated later.
then $\bigcup_{x\in E}B_x\supseteq E$.

Now, I claim that $ \{x\in E: \forall r. B(x,r)\cap E^\circ \neq \emptyset \land B(x,r)\cap E^{exterior}\neq \emptyset\}$ in negligible because each x that satisfies that belongs to $\partial E$ and hence this group is subset of negligible group and hence negligible itself.

Hence, for *almost* every x (except negligible set) we can choose $r_x$ such that $B_x\subseteq E$ and hence $\bigcup_{x\in E\\x\notin \partial E}B_x\subseteq E$ and therfore $$\int_{\bigcup_{x\in E\\x\notin \partial E}B_x}f = \int_Ef =(*)$$ and because $\int|f|<\infty$ over every open ball, then we got integrablity of $f$ over $E$

Second part: I claim that for each open set $U$ then $\int_Uf=v(U)$ because we can take an open ball $B$ such that $U\subseteq B$ and define $\tilde{f} = \cases{f\;\;x\in U\\0\;\;x \in B/U}$ and hence it is that $\int_B\tilde{f}=\int_Uf=v(U)$

Now we say that $(*)=v(\bigcup_{x\in E\\x\notin \partial E}B_x) = v(E)$ because the difference between the sets is negiligible.

Is my proof right? I am especially wondering if the claim in the second part is actually true and well explained?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: The proof has a problem: Your neighborhoods $B_x$ can overlap.  You need to fill your set up with a -countable- set of -disjoint- balls (up to a null set) and then take a limit of the sums of the integrals over $B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \dots \cup B_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  My hint: Based on your definition of Lebesgue measure (which I assume is built on unions of disjoint rectangles), prove it first for a rectangle - by further proving it for squares by covering an arbitrary rectangle (up to a null set) with squares.  Or if you have Riesz Representation Theorem it's a 1-line proof.

Comment: Hey @JohnSamples. Did you write about my first part of proof or the second? (or both?) And about your proposal: Your disjoint balls $B_1,B_2,..$  covers $E$ for every $n$ or just by limit? I was actually struggle to find a disjoint cover by balls to an open set.

Comment: The first part; you don't really know anything about that integral and whether it's finite, the domain it's taken over is not of the type that you are given information for a priori.  Also, an uncountable collection of $\partial(B_x)$ is not necessarily negligible, which I think you imply at one point later.  You need to decompose open sets into countable unions of disjoint balls (up to a null set).  Then everything will work fine.

Comment: Hey again @JohnSamples. The only proof I can think of is: $f$ is integrable over $E$ because $E$ is bounded, and hence I can take a (one) ball that covers $E$, and because $f$ is integrable over the ball it is also integrable over a subset of the ball which is $E$. (It's right, is it? by the definition of being integrable) and now the only thing I can think of is to show that the given $f$ is equal to $1$ on every continuity point of $f$ and hence the integral over $E$ equals to the volume of $E$.

Comment: Sadly, I wasn't able to decompose $E$ to disjoint balls. I was stuck because I came to the point that if $E$ is connected, then there is no way to write it as a union of two disjoint open sets.

Answer (score 1):

Formal solution of what I have pointed in the comments:

**Proof of the integrability of $f$:**

*claim:* $\mathcal{B}_f$ (denotes the set of points where $f$ is not continous) is negligible.

*proof*: Indeed, $\mathcal{B}_f = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{B}_{f|_{B(0,i)}}$ is a negligible set as $f$ is integrable over each open ball (corollary from *Lebesgue* sentence).

- *remark*: The above proof does not assume that countable union of negligible sets is negligible (it isn't necessarily), but that for each $i$ the set $\mathcal{B}_{f|_{B(0,i)}}$ is negligible, and each Jordan set $E$ is contained in such ball

*corollary*: Again, from *Lebesgue* $f$ is integrable over every bounded Jordan set.

**Proof of the property of $f$:**

*claim:* $f|_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\mathcal{B}_f}=1$

*proof:* Otherwise, there is continuity point ,$x$ of $f$ which satisfies (*WLOG*) that $f(x)>1$. Hence, there is an open neighborhood, $U_x$ of $x$ where $f(U_x)>1$ and as there can be found a ball, $B(x,\delta_{U_x})$ contained in $U_x$ by the linearity of Integrals: $\int_{B(x,\delta_{U_x})}f>\int_{B(x,\delta_{U_x})}1=vol(B(x,\delta_{U_x}))$ which contradicts the given.

*corollary:* $\int_E{f} = \int_{E\setminus\mathcal{B}f|_E}1+\int_{\mathcal{B}f|_E}f = vol(E)$